# Find Cell Value Utilizing Cell Name In Another Cell

Tags: excel

Say I have a cell (A1) with the text "n25". In another cell, I want to find the value of the cell defined in A1 in another cell, lets say A2. In other words how do I put =(text from another cell, in this case "n25", which would then return me the value in cell n25). The reason I ask is because the cell containing n25 will be dynamic as data changes (it can be n26 in which all other cells would update).

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
=INDIRECT(address_of_cell_with_reference_to_another_cell)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, try:

```
=INDIRECT(A1)
```

This will return the value from N25.